# How to use the HSET command in Redis cache from C# code?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am kind of new to Redis Cache. I have implemented calling the Redis server from my C# code by using this article [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1120038/A-simple-Csharp-cache-component-using-Redis-as-pro). I could able to set the values in Redis DB using the SetValue() method. But I am not sure on how to set Hash values in Redis cache from C# code and I couldn't able to get a good example on the internet. Please help me with this.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Have you tried HashSetAsync ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new entry to the hash using method `SetEntryInHash(string hashId, string key, string value)` or add a list of entries using method `SetRangeInHash(string hashId, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValuePairs)`

Comment: Will there be any performance difference of using "SetEntryInHash" and "SetRangeInHash"? For example I kind of having 4000 items. Will one by one entry in Redis is efficient or passing it as a collection is efficient?

Comment: I didnt test it out, but my guessing that establishing connection costs more that inserting a batch of records. I suggest to start testing with SetRangeInHash

Answer (score 3):

Docs are definitely vague on this. After skimming the repo, `SetEntryInHash` appears to be what you want.

```
        public bool SetEntryInHash(string hashId, string key, string value)
        {
            return base.HSet(hashId, key.ToUtf8Bytes(), value.ToUtf8Bytes()) == Success;
        }
```

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient_Hash.cs#L51-L54

Comment: Will there be any performance difference of using "SetEntryInHash" and "SetRangeInHash"? For example I kind of having 4000 items. Will one by one entry in Redis is efficient or passing it as a collection is efficient?

Comment: @Anish the performance is O(n) for both, and as of redis 4.0.0 HMSET has been deprecated in favor of using HSET with multiple field/value pairs. https://redis.io/commands/hmset